Collapsing sequence of noncompact 4-manifolds
I am reading about collapsing geometry, and I am curious after seeing examples of collapse in the lens spaces and Berger spheres in three dimensions whether similar phenomena occur in the setting of dimension 4. More precisely, I am trying to build a sequence of noncompact, complete Riemannian $4$-manifolds with positive Ricci curvature bounded above, say by $1$, such that their injectivity radii go to zero.
I have tried tinkering with products of $2$-dimensional paraboloids as well as the punctured space $\mathbb{R}^4\setminus\{0\}\simeq\mathbb{R}_+\times S^3$ with the "normalized" metric $(1/r^2)dr^2+g_{S^3}$, taking the sequence to be the quotients by $\mathbb{Z}/k$ (i.e., the manifolds $\mathbb{R}_+\times L(k,1)$, where $L(k,1)$ denotes the lens space, with the metric induced by the covering map). In all examples I've worked with so far, however, the Ricci curvature either vanishes in some direction or is too large and does not satisfy the upper bound that I'd like to impose. I'd appreciate any suggestions, examples, or references to the literature where similar examples are given.
